# Android crash stack trace- com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'y.navigate'), stack

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation-v5

I am seeing crashes for my react-native app on Google play console. The stack trace for the crash lists the following: -

```
com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'y.navigate'), stack:
onPress@4696:1046
touchableHandlePress@218:2269
touchableHandlePress@-1
_performSideEffectsForTransition@209:9693
_performSideEffectsForTransition@-1
_receiveSignal@209:8375
_receiveSignal@-1
touchableHandleResponderRelease@209:5663
touchableHandleResponderRelease@-1
b@92:1197
k@92:1340
C@92:1394
N@92:1692
A@92:2482
forEach@-1
z@92:2282
<unknown>@92:13914
_e@92:88659
Ne@92:13582
Ue@92:13755
receiveTouches@92:14547
value@31:3685
<unknown>@31:841
value@31:2939
value@31:813
value@-1
at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportException(Unknown Source
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke (Unknown Source:150)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke (Unknown Source:21)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run (Native Method)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:883)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:100)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage (Unknown Source)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:237)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run (Unknown Source:37)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:919)
```

Can anyone tell me the root cause of this issue? I am using the following from react-navigation library:

- "@react-navigation/native": "5.1.5"
- "@react-navigation/stack": "5.2.10"

Not sure if this issue is related to react-navigation at all, but it does say y.navigate in the stack trace.

Comment: Please, when this error happens? When you build? Is a certain part of your code? Please provide more details

Comment: I am not seeing any issue with my app when I use it on my phone; hence not able to reproduce any issue which could be related to this stack trace. But since other users are encountering this crash, as listed on Google play console, I am trying to figure out from the stack trace what the actual error is and when it happens in app.
There is no issue seen in my env either. It is a google playstore crashes feedback.

Comment: @sc344 This seems to be a android 12 and above issue